# Primeng Calendar form group not able to bind existing value

Tags: angular

I have an array of interest Rate(Date + Rate), I want to update existing values in edit page but existing date is not binding in p-calender. It is showing empty box.I am using the following code

```html
<p-calendar formControlName="rate_date" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="2000:2030"></p-calendar>
```

If I am using normal input date with ngModal it is working fine.

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="address.rate_date" formControlName="rate_date" type="date" value="{{ address.rate_date }}"                                 [ngClass]="(isSelectedRateDate==true)?'form-control event_l_cur_rate':'form-control event_l_cur_rate has-error'"                                     [attr.disabled]="disabled?'':null">
```

I attached here screenshot with my output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYaNB.png)

Comment: I am also facing same issue. How we can patch value to p calendar in edit form of reactive form